# Sharepoint 2010 : not able to deploy new sharepoint solution

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, web-config

I was working on Sharepoint visual solution, all my webparts works fine, I don't know what happened but when I create new visual webpart (with label in it)I was not able to deploy
error message :

```
Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': The process cannot access the file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\ch-dev80\web.config' because it is being used by another process.
```

I didn't open my web.config, and I am the only one working on the server.
I tried an IISreset, app pool retsart with no luck,
I went to the Central admin delete the solution, and I create new sharepoint project with an empty webpart (just a label to test) but when I deploy from VS or central admin I have this message in central admin :

```
 CH-xx : http://ch--dev/ : Portal : Error: The web.config could not be saved on this IIS Web Site: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\ch-dev80\web.config. 
The process cannot access the file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\ch-dev80\web.config' because it is being used by another process.
```

I don't know what to do.
Help please

Comment: Did you recycle the sharepoint timer service? Or restart the server?